# C# windows service crash

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service which process text files using a file watcher, which is working fine (thanks to your previous help).

My other part of the project is a portal, where I access the processed data, see a log of all activities (which I'm using listview with an update panel and timer).

Now I found that whenever I access the messages or the log, my service crashes, as the page try to load the messages (over 70000 records for 3 days only).
It might be due to the big number of records my portal is trying to read while the service is writing a new records at the same time.

I'm using Entity Framework and my catch is throwing this error "Error: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details"

My service and portal are updating the same log table on the DB (but I don't think this is the reason).

any idea?

Comment: When you catch an exception you should log `ex.ToString()`, that way you get to see the full error (including the inner exception that entity framework is referring to)

Comment: Service must be crashing(stopping) due to unhandled exception thrown within the service. Add proper exception handling and log the error message to see what is going wrong.

Comment: sorry, messages is my processed text files, I view them on the portal as listview repeater and check their status (after the service read the text, it send it via email). and the log is also a page with listvie with every activity listed (example: service is adding a record in the table for sent or unsent messages, also portal is logging every user logged in)

Comment: Thank you @Justin for your tip, I will add that later

Comment: note that I don't have this issue on my test server (very few test file processed compared to the live one)